# Create Image from Text File RGB Data in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, matrix

I have a text file with RGB data in the form of:

```
[Pixel 0,0] [Pixel 1,0] [Pixel 2,0]...
[Pixel 0,1] [Pixel 1,1] [Pixel 2,2]...
...
```

With an input of:

```
0.0 0.0 0.0 <-- this would be Pixel 0,0
1.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 0.9 0.0
```

I can create the flag of Germany in size 3x1 with:

```
%load the data to myData
Germany = reshape(myData,3,1,3);
image(Germany)
```

[image: This is an image]

The 1px-wide pattern works good as show in picture, however, the goal is to be able to create multiple patterns, e.g. the Germany flag in 3x3 followed by Romania flag in 3x3 or any other pattern of any length and doing **that!** is where I can not find the proper way to reshape the matrix.

The input that should create the second example shown in picture is this:

```
         |========= Germany Flag ==========| [   Blue  ] [ Yellow  ] [   Red   ]
Black -> 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.9 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
Red ->   1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.9 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
Yellow-> 1.0 0.9 0.0 1.0 0.9 0.0 1.0 0.9 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.9 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
```

Any help is appreciated

**Update:** Asked by Marcin, the input files are literal as I explained above.
This is the content of the GermanyRomania.txt file:

```
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.9 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.9 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 0.9 0.0 1.0 0.9 0.0 1.0 0.9 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.9 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
```

With that file I must create the 2nd pattern in picture (German+Romania Flag), there is ALL the RGB info required to do it.

Comment: Not clear what your input data is. Can you provide more examples, or the example files you are using?

Comment: @Marcin I have included an example of the input, however, it is exactly as the one that I have already posted before, take it literal to avoid confusion, as it looks it **is**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve what you want by simply using the `reshape` function.

We must take into account that Matlab stores matrices in **column-major order** (you can read more about it [here](http://www.matlabtips.com/columns-and-rows-are-not-the-same/)).

Therefore, before we can use the `reshape` function, we must have the data matrix in the following format:

```
[Pixel 0,0]
[Pixel 0,1]
...
[Pixel 1,0]
[Pixel 1,1]
...
[Pixel n,n]
```

Here's a possible solution:

```
# data stores the input
height = size(data, 1)
width = size(data, 2)
vertical_data_cell = mat2cell(data, height, 3 * ones(1, width / 3))'
vertical_data = cell2mat(vertical_data_cell)
flags = reshape(vertical_data, height, width / 3, 3)
image(flags)
```

Note that we make the matrix transformation on lines 4 and 5.

And here is the result for the input you provided:

[image]

It also works with different heights.
Here's the input for the flags of Germany, Argentina and Portugal.

```
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.46 0.66 0.85 0.46 0.66 0.85 0.46 0.66 0.85
1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.98 0.75 0.29 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 0.9 0.0 1.0 0.9 0.0 1.0 0.9 0.0 0.46 0.66 0.85 0.46 0.66 0.85 0.46 0.66 0.85
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.9 0.0 1.0 0.9 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
```

And this is the result:
[image]